How to resolve values from other subgraphs deep in a nested query in Apollo?
Let's say I have the following federated graph:
type Query {
    products: [Product]!
}

// resolved by `discounts-service`
type Discount {
    priceWithDiscount: Float
    expired: Boolean
}

// resolved by `pricing-service`
type Price @key(fields: "sku") @extends {
    sku: String!
    amount: Int!
    discount: Discount! @requires(fields: "amount")
}

// resolved by `products-service`
type Product @key(fields: "sku") {
    sku: String!
    title: String!
    price: Price!
}

So, in summary, I have a query returning n products. Each Product has a Price, which has a Discount node.
However, now let's say that the Discount is now tied to individual users. So now the resolver must know at least two properties about the user who is querying: its id and segmentation.
So we have an User node like:
// resolved by `users-service`
type User @key(fields: "id") {
    id: String!
    name: String!
    segmentation: String!
    // ....
}

Now, how can I make the discounts-service receive those properties (User data) in an efficient* manner in a Federated Apollo Schema?
*I'm saying efficient because a naive solution, such as just adding User as @external in the Product/Price node would make Apollo Router to call the users-service for the same user for each product in the array, unnecessarily.
--
A possible solution would be adding parameters to the discount node:
type Price @key(fields: "sku") @extends {
    // ...
    discount(userId: String!, segmentation: String!): Discount! @requires(fields: "amount")
}

However, such solution requires the caller to first fetch the user data and the input values are untrustworthy since it's given by the client and not fetched by the Apollo Router (i.e., a user can lie about its segmentation).

For something like this, assuming your User is somehow authenticated on the platform, I'd pass an optional Authorization header to the request in the form of a Bearer: <token> scheme. Then, in your resolver, call a getUserDiscount helper function that does the following:

if no token scheme is present, return null or some other specific value, and compute the basic discount as you already did with no specific User discount attached,
if the token scheme is present, validate the token, and throw on invalid scheme/token,
using the userId found inside the validated token, get the id and segmentation for that user and return these values to your resolver for further computation and/or forwarding as data in your response.

This way you don't have an extra GraphQL request, everything is handled on the server side, and relatively safe too since you'll be validating the (JWT) token against a secret. But again this assumes the User is authenticated, which I believe is a sensical assumption in this context.
You can then re-use this helper function whenever necessary, although in your particular use case it'd make sense to have it on the resolver for the discount field only.

I like your approach. However, our Auth provider does not support custom properties in JWT tokens. Do you have any suggestion?

@voyager11 You do not need to set custom properties inside the token. All you need in the token is a unique user identifier (usually an ID, but an email would also work for instance) that will allow you, inside the helper function, after the token has been decoded and you have that unique identifier, to then fetch the relevant discount data from your database.

That's exactly what I would like to avoid: fetching from database. Because all those services have independent databases. I would like Apollo Federation to get the user once when the query is made and pass it down to the resolvers, so the Discount service won't need to reach any other service to discover the segmentation.

Sorry for the misunderstanding as I do not have visibility into the details of your project :D But my point still stands, the unique user identifier found in a token should be enough info to retrieve the data you're after (the corresponding segmentation) - whether from a DB, an internal GraphQL request, cache or federation. Once the token is decoded, you could query your users-service once using that ID, retrieve the corresponding segmentation, and hand it back to your resolver, for example.
